# Is SolrJ 7.7.3 Backward compatible with SolrJ 6.6?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solr7

I am using SolrJ client 7.7 in one of my service and SolrJ client 6.6 in another.
So just want to know if,
Is SolrJ 7.7.3 Backward compatible with SolrJ 6.6?

Comment: it could be compatible and they must have added some new classes/feature to the newer solrj version.

Comment: The question is more about compatibility between your Solr server version and SolrJ clients. Your two SolrJ clients don't interact directly.